# Fill remaining screen height below non-fixed header of unkown size

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the layout of the snippet below:

- non-fixed navbar at the top with unknown height
- fill the remaining screen space with the `#title div`
- the article continues after the title (not visible on the screen initially, only after scrolling down)

The problem with this snippet is, that it completely breaks the semantic hierarchy of the HTML. The `#uglyWrapper` splits the article in two parts.

I could use  `#title { height: calc(100vh - $nav-height) }`, but the top bar is a flexbox itself. So `$nav-height` is unknwon.

**Is there a CSS-only solution, that doesn't mess with this HTML structure:**

```
body
    nav
    article
        #title
        text
```

---

Snippet demonstrating, how it should *look* like:

```css
#uglyWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="uglyWrapper">
    <nav>top nav with unknown height, not fixed</nav>
  <!--  article -->
    <div id="title">Full height title image</div>
  </div>
  Article continues <br>
  much text <br>
  much text <br>
  much text
  <!-- /article -->
</body>
```

---

**Addressing [mfluehr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3469273/mfluehr):**

This approach doesn't fill the remaining space. Instead it fills the entire screen height and gets clipped by the header bar. I left the details about the image intentionally out of the question asking for a div instead. Because there are other elements in that div, that require precise layouting. So covering up an area of unknown size is problematic. Please don't get stuck on the details of the image and use to the minimal example. I can get it working from there.

Comment: Can you provide an image with the correct layout? I am having some trouble understanding it to be honest

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle you can ignore the image and use a div as in the snippet. I will set `object-fit: cover` so the image size won't matter here.

Comment: I will take a look when I am home.

Comment: `#title div` has `height: 100%;` and fills all remaining empty space as i can see from your snippet. What is the question?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you elaborate further? If you just want to stack things up you could just set their widths and fill them with content. Provided that is you don't have bootstrap css interfering with what it is you're trying to do here.

Comment: @kevinwalker there is not Bootsrap involved. I want the screen size to dictate where the content goes. Not merely stack up content and hope that it fits exactly in one screen height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave [ЖнецЪ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690294/1871117) the bounty, because he gave the first answer, that fulfilled all the criteria.

In the final solution however, die `grid`-approach did not work for me after adding the `<img>` into the title. For some screen sizes the image forced the title the be taller than allowed.

---

So I diverted back to the flexbox and discovered that my original mistake was a missing `height: 100%` (not in the question). Not giving all the ancestor elements of the image up to the flexbox `height: 100%` was the problem.

This snippet has the desired HTML structure without the `ugglyWrapper` and a full screen placeholder image.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*  This does not work for wide and slim screen sizes */
  /*   display: grid; */
  /*   grid-template-rows: auto 1fr; */
}

nav {
  background-color: gray;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#title {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

article {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>top nav with unknown height, not fixed</nav>
  <article>
    <div id="title">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyIkU.png">
    </div>
    Article continues <br> much text <br> much text <br>
  </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply absolute positioning to the `<nav>`. Since the title image will use `object-fit: cover`, it shouldn't matter if a chunk from the top is covered by the navigation.

```css
#title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>top nav with unknown height, not fixed</nav>
  <article>
    <div id="title">Full height title image</div>
    much text <br>
    much text <br>
    much text
  </article>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this goes into the right direction. I addressed some issues with it on my question above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try this solution with by adding `display: grid` on the `#uglyWrapper` element.

```css
#uglyWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid; /* new line */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 0%; /* new line */
}
```

```css
#uglyWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid; /* new line */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 0%; /* new line */
}

nav {
  background-color: hsl(0 0% 50% / 0.5);
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#title {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="uglyWrapper">
  <nav>top nav with unknown height, not fixed</nav>
  <!--  article -->
  <div id="title">Full height title image</div>
  Article continues <br /> much text <br /> much text <br />
  <!-- /article -->
</div>
```